# Can we schedule a notebook using schedule from other notebook?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I tried this it is not helping. Can someone please look into it?

```
import schedule
import time
def test():
    %run ./Final.ipynb
schedule.every().day.at('17:04').do(test)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: if may be possible, but this is a terrible idea

Comment: why don't you just put your code in a script?